# How to move columns with drag and drop in Excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-excel-2016

How to move/reorder columns with drag and drop in Excel 2016 for Mac? The [method that worked for Excel 2011](https://superuser.com/questions/266356/how-to-move-columns-with-drag-and-drop-in-excel-2011) no longer works in 2016. The cursor never changes to the pointer or hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tested this on Excel 15.14(150911) and it worked as called out in your linked article with the exception that the cursor turned to a gloved hand. Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> "squeezed" the hand and I was able to move my column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Excel 15.13.1 when I asked the question. Now, I am using 15.14, and it does work as you describe with one caveat: there is a smaller area where the cursor can be before it will change into the hand. The center of the cursor must be exactly on the left edge of the selected column and also exactly on the bottom line of the column header. In other words, the bottom-left corner of the header. It seems more picky than Excel 2011, and the cursor must be slightly below center rather than at the vertical center.

Comment: Duh! Michael is right (trying on v 15.17 here). I was aready losing my mind over this. So, this is just utterly crappy UX, but hey, it's Microsoft, what do you expect? Have you ever tried this in Numbers? I wonder why I ever opened Excel in the first place.

Comment: I had this problem on 15.31. Upgraded to 15.36 and move and (shift) drag are back - anywhere along the bottom edge of the row

Comment: I'm on 16.6, and I can't get the hand or drag a column, regardless of whether I hold shift or where I put my cursor 